# How to get all data from a table which you also query for AVG

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I need help on solving the query problem below.. **Thanks in advance**.
I have three tables

> `attachments` 
>   `sun_individual`
>   `sun_reviews`

I want to select user `names, profession and reviewed` by his/her `ID` from `sun_individual` and `join` with his `profile photo` from table `attachments` then get his/her `reviews (each review and rate)` and the `average RATE`

`TABLE : sun_individual`

```
id|sun_id|first_name|last_name |sun_profession|sun_verified_date|sun_verified|flg
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20|SV-001|Alex      | James    | Doctor       |2017-12-08       | 1         |1           
21|SV-002|Jane      | Rose     | Programmer   |2017-12-08       | 1         |1
```

`TABLE: sun_reviews`

```
id|user_id|rev_txt   |rev_rate|rev_date  |flg                                    
----------------------------------------------------                                
1 |20     | the best | 4      |2017-12-09|1
2 |21     | know CLI | 2      |2017-12-09|1
3 |20     | recommend| 3      |2017-12-09|0
4 |20     | so far   | 3      |2017-12-09|1
```

`TABLE: attachments`

```
id|user|type    |path              |flg
----------------------------------------
88|20  |passport|/upload/img128.jpg|1
89|21  |passport|/upload/img008.jpg|1
```

`flg:1` means the value is **active**, `flg:0`the value is to be **ignored**

`My Code is :`

```
SELECT 
      sun_reviews.rev_txt As txtReview, sun_reviews.rev_date As dateReview,
      sun_reviews.rev_rate As rateReview,

      AVG(sun_reviews.rev_rate) As avgREV,
      concat(sun_individual.first_name, sun_individual.last_name) As name,

      sun_individual.sun_profession As profession, 
      sun_individual.sun_verified_date As dateVerified,

      CASE when sun_verified = 1 then 'VERIFIED' else 'EXPIRED' END As status,

      attachments.path As photo 
FROM `sun_individual`

     LEFT JOIN sun_reviews ON sun_reviews.user_id = sun_individual.id
     INNER JOIN attachments ON attachments.user = sun_individual.id

WHERE attachments.type = 'passport' AND attachments.flg = 1 
      AND sun_reviews.flg = 1 AND sun_individual.flg = 1 
      AND sun_individual.sun_id LIKE '%SV-001'
```

What I want to archive is when someone is looking for user (let say SV-001) when the code is inputted to get result like

`result for: SV-001`

```
txtReview|dateReview|rateReview|avgREV|name      |profession | dateVerified | photo
------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------------
the best |2017-12-09|4         |3.5000|Alex James| Doctor    | 2017-12-08   |/upload/img128.jpg  
so far   |2017-12-09|3         |3.5000|Alex James| Doctor    | 2017-12-08   |/upload/img128.jpg
```

I want to get result like the one **above**, however when I ran the query I get only one review

```
txtReview|dateReview|rateReview|avgREV|name      |profession | dateVerified | photo
------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------------
the best |2017-12-09|4         |3.5000|Alex James| Doctor    | 2017-12-08   |/upload/img128.jpg
```

I think there is something am doing wrong... If you know the solution to my problem kindly help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  a.rev_txt                    as txtReview,
  a.rev_date                   as dateReview,
  a.rev_rate                   as rateReview,
  d.avgRev                     as avgRev,
  b.first_name || b.last_name  as name,
  b.sun_profession             as profession, 
  b.sun_verified_date          as dateVerified,
  case
    when sun_verified = 1 then 'VERIFIED' 
    else 'EXPIRED' 
  end                          as status,
  c.path                       as photo
from
  sun_reviews a
  join
  sun_individual b
  on a.user_id = b.id
  join
  attachments c
  on c.user_id = b.id
  join
  (
    select 
      user_id,
      avg(rev_rate) as avgRev
    from
      sun_reviews
    where
      flg = 1
    group by 
      user_id
  ) d
  on d.user_id = b.id
where
  c.type = 'passport' and
  c.flg = 1 and
  a.flg = 1 and 
  b.flg = 1 and
  b.sun_id LIKE '%SV-001';

 txtreview | datereview | ratereview |       avgrev       |   name    | profession | dateverified |  status  |       photo        
-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+--------------------
 the best  | 2017-12-09 |          4 | 3.5000000000000000 | AlexJames | Doctor     | 2017-12-08   | VERIFIED | /upload/img128.jpg
 so far    | 2017-12-09 |          3 | 3.5000000000000000 | AlexJames | Doctor     | 2017-12-08   | VERIFIED | /upload/img128.jpg
(2 rows)
```

When you have a group by, all columns in the result set must be either group by columns or aggregates.  I guess you are using MySQL which does not enforce this.  You should enforce it yourself though, otherwise it gets very confusing.

Comment: The query worked perfectly, thank you. I will also look into that " **You should enforce it yourself though** " . Thank You